# Epson V300 Photo scanner and RaspberryPi

Tags: linux, drivers, raspberry-pi, scanner

I am trying to install Epson V300 Photo scanner to share it over network with my RaspberryPi (running Raspbian "wheezy").
The scanner is not supported by sane, but it has its own epkowa drivers. Unfortunately they don't have an arm package, so I tried to compile from source.
I have installed iscan_2.29.1-5.tar.gz and iscan-data_1.23.0-1.tar.gz, but I can't get my scanner to be recognized.
Doing a `sane-find-scanner -q` I see my scanner listed with all the information, but when I try `scanimage -L` I get `No scanners were identified`.

Answer (score 2):

The drivers are x86 binary, no source code distributed. So asking EPSON to compile the code for ARM is the only viable solution (or an emulator perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

This guy's worked it out. You need to compile the drivers yourself (easy enough)
http://www.johndscomputers.com/2013/geek-friday/geek-friday-setting-up-epson-scanning-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Instead of just providing a link, summarize the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient scanner that I doubt anyone uses anymore, but... I figured out how to compile the driver from source (link was deprecated, of course!).

Epson also offers an ARM binary that you can try before proceeding below:

https://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php#arm

Get the source code from the Epson website for iscan and iscan-data (You'll find the website yourself here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=97929&DSCCHK=b5543797f2c23898f1b6b9fc37e81a56b7daac40):

```
wget http://support.epson.net/linux/src/scanner/iscan/iscan_2.30.4-2.tar.gz

wget http://support.epson.net/linux/src/scanner/iscan/iscan-data_1.39.2-1.tar.gz
```

Unpack:

```
tar -xvf iscan_2.30.4-2.tar.gz
```

Install dependences:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev libxml2-dev libsane-dev xsltproc
```

Compile (README says to install iscan-data before iscan):

```
./configure
sudo make
```

Install:

```
sudo make install
```

NOW there are some additional steps that for some reason the EPSON script doesn't take care of that we need to do before the scanner will work.

```
sudo adduser saned lp
```

In /etc/udev/rules.d/55-libsane.rules (create if it doesn’t exist):

```
SYSFS{idVendor}=="04b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

In /etc/sane.d/epson2.conf and epson.conf, change the line that says usb to read:

```
usb <vendor ID> <product ID>
```

(You can get that info from running sane-find-scanner.)

You might have to restart and then

```
sudo scanimage --list-devices
```

should display the scanner.

Last steps originally found here: https://www.johndstech.com/how-to/geek-friday-setting-up-epson-scanning-on-raspberry-pi/